# Error thrown when trigger method called in pusher, "expected string"

Tags: node.js, pusher

I'm trying to configure pusher on my nodejs app.

```
const Pusher = require("pusher");
const pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: "id",
    key: "key",
    secret: "secret",
    cluster: "ap2",
    useTLS: true,
});
pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
    message: "Hello, world."
}).then(console.log).catch(e=> console.log(e))
```

When I put above code in index and run, I get following error message.

```
{
  name: 'PusherRequestError',
  message: 'Unexpected status code 400',
  url: 'a URL with all secret and stuff',
  error: undefined,
  status: 400,
  body: 'expected string\n'
}
```

I double-checked the keys, secrets, etc and they are all correct. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've copied your exact publishing code to my app and it works okay.
Might be best to get in touch with Pusher Support so you can share the full URL as it may help with identifying the issue. https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Appreciate it, will check with them.

Comment: @doydoy They just replied and they said the same. The code I was using is correct and they tried from their end and worked. Also, we both had the same node and pusher versions. I even tried pushing the code to the dev server (AWS) and got the same issue. Not sure what's wrong, strange.  :|

Comment: I don't see any error in your code. Do you use any transpiler or runtime library that may change the code or its behavior? (e.g. Webpack)

Comment: I downgraded the pusher to v3.0.0, and it's working just fine now. That older version gets the job done so I didn't go too deep into the problem. One thing is for sure, the issue isn't with the environment nor versions (node, pusher). Because the same combination works for others.